# jest spy on a mocked function from the mock file

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I have some business logic and a mock file:

`/services/myService.ts`

`/services/__mocks__/myService.ts.`

I have a test file `/tests/myService.test.ts` which contains the line:

`jest.mock('../services/myService');`

This mock file, amongst other things, mocks a function `myFunction`

I want to be able to spy on the function, `myFunction` inside
`/services/__mocks__/myService.ts.` (the mock file) to ensure that it is being called (and see what it returned).

Is this possible in jest?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I get it correctly: you should import needed function from mocked module right before mocking module.

I guess in your case that should work:

```
import {myFunction} from '../services/myService.ts';
jest.mock('../services/myService');
...
expect(myFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```